# Timer doesn't raise during long event

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I am trying to present to operator timer 00:00 on the start button event ( that start my program - long time event ) I enabled the timer but it doesn't tick only when the event finished or if message box occur .

I am using C# form timer .

Any idea how to implement in C# timer during long event ? I think is related to threading timer ? Any Example ? Please help ! thanks

```
private void Timer_elapsed_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timeSec++;
        if(timeSec >= 60)
        {
            timeSec = 0;
            timeMin++;
        }
        DrawTime();
    }

    private void DrawTime()
    {
        lbSec.Text = string.Format("{0:00}", timeSec);
        lbMin.Text = string.Format("{0:00}", timeMin);
    }

private void start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      timer_elapsed.Enabled = true;
      //do some event (long time) 
      //timer not works during this event 


    }
// when the event finished timer works
```

Comment: The timer is raised on the UI thread and as long as the UI thread is busy with your code it will not be raised.

Comment: Related: [Timer doesn't raise during of long event is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64912359/c-sharp-timer-doesnt-raise-during-of-long-event-is-running)

Comment: I agree we that , how to solve it ?

Comment: @klaus Gutter,ok .what is the solution?

Comment: Don't do the long processing directly in the Click event. You might use any async event handler, or fire up a background thread.

Comment: thanks you are right but finally i decided to use Application.DoEvents();

Answer (score -1):

I think timer control not associated with Tick event. check your your code form designer cs whether you configured wired events handlers correctly for "Timer_elapsed_Tick".   `this.timer_elapsed.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.Timer_elapsed_Tick);`

Comment: The OP stated "it doesn't tick only when the event finished or if message box occur" which effectively says that the event is wired up.

Answer (score -1):

solutions:
1.To works with System.Timers.Timer and not the windows form timer .
2.Add on click event Application.DoEvents .

Comment: Do NOT ever ever ever use `Application.DoEvents()`. It's only in the framework for backward compatibility with VB6. It is pure evil.